# violation of "Unique Particle Attribution"

Tags: validation, xsd

when I want to validate my xsd file, I got this error

cos-nonambig: "my xsd file":layout and "my xsd file":layout (or elements from their substitution group) violate "Unique Particle Attribution". During validation against this schema, ambiguity would be created for those two particles.

and refers me to this tag

```
<xs:complexType name="pageType">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element type="main:layoutType" name="layout" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:group ref="main:WidgetsGroup" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name"/>

    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="layout"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="dataModel"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="domain"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

what is the problem? and how could I fix it?

Comment: this error raised when validating my xsd file, there is not any xml file

Comment: it occurred because my group tag contains a layout tag that conflict with the above layout tag, and solved when removed layout tag from the WidgetsGroup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved it by inserting WidgetGroup contents to my xsd as :

```
<xs:complexType name="pageType">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element type="main:layoutType" name="layout" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="spinner" type="main:SpinnerType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="datePicker" type="main:DatePickerType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="button" type="main:ButtonType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="combo" type="main:ComboBoxType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="checkBox" type="main:CheckBoxType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="radioButton" type="main:RadioButtonType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="image" type="main:ImageType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="label" type="main:LabelType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="listBox" type="main:ListBoxType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <xs:element name="textBox" type="main:TextBoxType" minOccurs="0"/>
                <!--<xs:element name="layout" type="main:layoutType" minOccurs="0"/>-->
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>

    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name"/>

    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="layout"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="dataModel"/>
    <xs:attribute type="main:domainType" name="domain"/>
    <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="title"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: How does that work. The ambigous "layout" element is still there?